how to create an audio file which processingFormat is in16 in swift?
This is my code, processingFormat is always <AVAudioFormat 0x3016b46e0:  1 ch,  16000 Hz, Float32>, how to make it to be Int16?
   `let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

    let audioURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("recording_\(UUID().uuidString).wav")
    let int16Format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, sampleRate: 16000, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!

    do {
        audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: audioURL, settings: int16Format.settings)
        if let processingFormat = audioFile?.processingFormat {
            print("Processing format: \(processingFormat)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating audio file: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }


I get it! it should be
init(forWriting: URL, settings: [String : Any], commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat, interleaved: Bool)
